# Azure B2C DateTime Custom Claim / User Attribute as String

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to add custom claim to an Azure B2C User Flow. The value for this claim is an ISO8601 formatted string. I want it treated as a string but Azure B2C seems to be doing a type-conversion on the string in the background and is giving me the following error:

> There was an error trying to log you in: 'AADB2C99072: One of the claim values returned by restful call does not match with the claim type defined in the policy B2C_1_SignInSignUp of tenant .onmicrosoft.com: The data type 'DateTime' of the claim with id 'extension_claimname' does not match the DataType 'String' of ClaimType with id 'extension_claimname' specified in the policy.

The user attribute is setup as a string in Azure B2C.

The API Connector returns:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": "Continue",
    "extension_claimname": "2023-05-09T00:15:00.0000000Z"
}
```

Even though it's a date/time value I just want it treated as a string. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this as Azure B2C is trying to be "helpful" in the middle of things.

I have another claim in the mix that's a boolean that I'm also treating as a string and Azure B2C is handling that one as a string.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to a custom policy?

Comment: How did you manage to resolve this. Did you end up changing the attribute's type? Or did you find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [claims transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/date-transformations), you will note that there is no date to string. So custom policies won't help.

The only way around this is to change the API or add another API to do the conversion.

Comment: I think the issue is the reverse. Where a automatic conversion of a value returned from the API connector that looks like a date (ISO-8601) to a date but the underlying attribute has a string type causing the error.