# Azure AD B2C API Connector response automatically converts ISO-8601 formatted user attribute to DateTime

Tags: datetime, azure-ad-b2c

I am experiencing an issue where we have a custom user attribute ("LastLoginDate") which contains an ISO-8601 formatted date-time e.g. "2023-09-29T12:04:26.7639519Z"

We've recently noticed that some attributes we update in the API Connector connected to our "Sign Up Sign In" based user flow do not have the updated value in the token passed to our application.

To work around this I'm currently ensuring that the values for any updated attributes are being included in the connector response.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "action": "continue",
  "extension_<ApplicationID>_LastLoginDate": "2023-09-29T12:04:26.7639519Z"
}
```

When we do this though, I'm getting an error which seems to imply that the user attribute has the wrong type.

> AADB2C99072: One of the claim values returned by restful call does not match with the claim type defined in the policy B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn of tenant xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com: The data type 'DateTime' of the claim with id 'extension_<ApplicationId>_LastLoginDate' does not match the DataType 'String' of ClaimType with id 'extension_LastLoginDate' specified in the policy.
> Correlation ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
> Timestamp: 2023-09-29 12:04:27Z

Given that the only valid types for User Attributes are String, Int and Boolean, the error doesn't make sense. Why is there an automatic conversion from string to date with a user attribute that cannot be a DateTime.

I came across another question with the same error but no satisfactory answer here: [Azure B2C DateTime Custom Claim / User Attribute as String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76203973/592958)

Is there any way to prevent this automatic conversion?
Is this a bug in Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem like a bug if the built-in user-flows does not handle this conversion. I would raise a ticket with Microsoft support, if possible.

If I knew more about what you were trying to achieve then I could potentially give you some better workarounds, however based on the information provided, I would return an EPOCH value representing the last login datetime, which can be stored as an INT64 datatype in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Never thought about an alternative way to represent the date time. We're using UTC so storing as a timestamp should be sufficient. Do you have a link to any documentation confirming the use of 64 bit integers?

Comment: No problem. The Microsoft Graph [create identityUserFlowAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityuserflowattribute-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) request body has the underlying datatype

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
<ClaimsTransformation Id="DateTimeToString" TransformationMethod="Custom" ReferenceId="DateTimeToStringTransformation">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimType="extension_LastLoginDate" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimType="extension_LastLoginDateAsString" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: We are not using cutom flows. How would I use this with the standard Sign Up Sign In user flow?

Comment: https://girishgodage.in/blog/azure-acticedirectoryB2C_CreateUserFlow

Comment: The question is asking how to circumvent the automatic date conversion encountered when using the standard Sign Up Sign In user flow when attempting to return a an ISO-8601 formatted date time from an API connector.